# how multi tenancy is supported in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just wondering how multi-tenancy is supported in ElasticSearch? Multi-tenancy means that different customers can have different index. Would ElasticSearch builds different index per customer or a single index (a kind of sparse index)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you are correct. Multi-tenancy in ElasticSearch means:

- Configure indices assigned to specific user accounts
- Configure aliases with specific filtering/routing that can be assigned to specific user accounts

Hope that helps...